# Casimirs of Lie Algebras

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Are the eigenvalues of the Casimir of the lie algebra continuous if the corresponding lie group is noncompact and discrete is the lie group is compact ? One example I know is $SU(2)$ group, the Casimir of its corresponding lie algebra is discrete and are labelled by $j \in \mathbb{N}$ while the Casimir of the Lorentz algebra is continuous and is labelled by $m \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Is this a general fact ? If so, how do we prove it ?

Comment: Probably you need the Lie group to be semisimple, for the question to make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to know if the above trend is general, if it isn't, what are the conditions in which it is valid.